# Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: codeigniter, php

Install "xampp-win32-1.7.3.exe" and put my php project in htdocs folder. this is working on another machine which having PHP version of 5.3 same version is here also but gives me following error

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value
>   of new by reference is deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\businesscaliber\system\codeigniter\Common.php
>   on line 62 A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: Function
>   set_magic_quotes_runtime() is
>   deprecated
>
> Filename: codeigniter/CodeIgniter.php
>
> Line Number: 45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have your codeigniter version updated to the last version.

Comment: PHP Info gives PHP Version 5.3.1 which is latest one

Comment: not PHP version, CI version. Redownload CI from the site - i'd recommend using 2.0 as it'll be live in the near future, but you should be using CI 1.7.2 as a minimum

Comment: Yeah CI version. Not PHP version :)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of deprecation is Old version like PHP 4 which affects the

```
this->wsdl =& new wsdl($this->wsdlFile,$this->proxyhost,$this->proxyport,$this->proxyusername,$this->proxypassword,$this->timeout,$this->response_timeout);
```

and

```
$GLOBALS['_transient']['static']['nusoap_base']->globalDebugLevel = 9;
```

all you need to do is Comment them find them in the Line numbers and run again. Goodluck!